# How do I execute code after pytest generates a report (using pytest)?

Tags: pytest

So I'm trying to automatically SFTP an html report (that pytest creates) to a server after pytest finishes execution. Does this exist in pytest or do I have to create a wrapper?

I know there are "setup" and "teardown" methods and there exists a teardown method that you can execute after all the tests have ran, but this occurs BEFORE the report is generated (not what I want!).

Answer (score 6):

You can handle this in [pytest_unconfigure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_unconfigure) hook. If you are using [pytest-html](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html) to generate your test reports, you can do something like this to access the path of the reports

```py
# in conftest.py
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    html_report = config._html.logfile   # provides full path of generated html report
    # or
    html_report = config.option.htmlpath  # provides the value passed with --html command line option
    # your code to upload to sftp goes here
```